# SQL - Shortening a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a reputation system on my site, similar to Stack Overflow, where a member will get points for doing different tasks. One of these tasks is commenting on blog articles.

I only want to give my user 5 points for writing 1 comment on an article. If they write additional comments on the same article, or reply to other comments within that article, they should still only get the first 5 points.

To do this I've been querying the blog_comments table first, checking to see if that member has already posted a comment on that article previously, if not, in another query, I will add the 5 points to the members_reputation table. My example below shows this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicates_found FROM blog_comments
WHERE member_id = 12722 AND article_id = 30202

// in my server-side language I would have
// if duplicates_found = 0 then

INSERT INTO members_reputation (member_id, awarded_for, awarded_when, awarded_what)
VALUES (12722, 'Posted a comment', Now(), 5)
```

Is there a way to shorten these two queries to make one single one? I was thinking about adding the select query to my insert query as a sub-query, but I'll be honest, it confused me quite a lot as I'm not even sure I can use INSERT & WHERE together, can I?

Anyway, any suggestions are always gratefully received.

**MY ANSWER**

Thanks to Michael's kind answer, the answer to my question is:

```
INSERT INTO members_reputation (member_id, awarded_for, awarded_when, awarded_what)
SELECT 12722, 'Posted a comment', Now(), 5 FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM blog_comments
    WHERE member_id = 12722 AND article_id = 30202
)
```

Comment: An `INSERT` can have sub queries to fetch a particular column value. However, you cannot use a `WHERE` with an INSERT statement. Do you always want to insert a new reputation or only if duplicate not found?

Comment: I only want to insert new reputation if the user has *not* previously posted a comment on that article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO members_reputation (member_id, awarded_for, awarded_when, awarded_what)
select 12722, 'Posted a comment', Now(), 5
where not exists
(
    select * FROM blog_comments
    WHERE member_id = 12722 AND article_id = 30202
)
```

**UPDATE:**

@MartinG I don't have MySQL in my box. I tried it on http://sqlzoo.net though, seems MySQL is like Oracle, SELECT with no source table requires a dummy table, you can use DUAL table in lieu of dummy table

```
select 'hello' as "No, it is right!" from dual where 
exists( SELECT * FROM bbc
  WHERE name = 'China')
```

Comment: I think I understand what's going on there. I've just tried it in my query window and got a syntax error on line 3, starting at WHERE NOT EXISTS. Any clues?

Comment: Use DUAL table. `select 12722, 'Posted a comment', Now(), 5 FROM DUAL`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for the answer and update. Going to read about DUAL now, as this is the first time I have seen it.